# Capture two events in two overlapped elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs that are overlapped with two mouse-events. Is it possible to capture both events? I'm only able to capture A or B, but not A and B at the same time.

```js
function adown() {
  console.log('A')
}

function bdown() {
  console.log('B')
}
```

```css
#a {
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}

#b {
  pointer-events: all;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a" onmousedown="adown()"></div>
<div id="b" onmousedown="bdown()"></div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`document.elementsFromPoint`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `document.elementsFromPoints(x,y)` where x and y are from mouseposition on the document `onclick` event. Then, just "filter" the elements by wrapping them up in a `div`, in this code with id canvas. And lastly, just `console.log` their `id`.

As you can see in this snippet:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let els = document.elementsFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    els.forEach(function(el){
        if(document.querySelector("#canvas").contains(el)){
            console.log(el.id);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#A {
    pointer-events: all;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background:red;
    position: absolute;
}
#B {
    pointer-events: all;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background:blue;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 50px;
    left:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvas">
<div id="A"></div>
<div id="B"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This would be a good answer if OP wanted to call some function for a certain set of elements. What I think OP want to do is to call different functions, both declared on different elements at once

Comment: Easy mate, please look at my answer. Doing things your way we can only call one function. You could of course specify function behavior per ID

Comment: Yeah, you're right, upvoting your answer, definitelly much more widelly usefull than what I did.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `document.elementsFromPoints` from previous answers and use an attribute to describe which function you want to call on click you'd be able to fire two function with one click.

```js
const functions = {
   funcA: () => console.log('A'),
   funcB: () => console.log('B'),
}

document.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const elements = document.elementsFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    elements.forEach(el => {
        if(document.querySelector("#container").contains(el)){
        const functionAttribute = el.getAttribute('data-function');
            if(functionAttribute && functionAttribute.length && functions[functionAttribute]){
            functions[functionAttribute]();
          }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.elem {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div data-function="funcA" class="elem">A</div>
  <div data-function="funcB" class="elem">B</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can assign both divs the same class and then iterate over them:

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

```js
const testDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
testDivs.forEach(testDiv => {
   testDiv.addEventListener('click', () => {
       // do something...
   });
});
```